# Why should I use sha256 or sha512 and not something else with hash_hmac?

Tags: php, hash

So I'm working on this project that needs a keyed hash to secure the outcome and I'm using hash_hmac(sha512, $data, $key) but sometimes it times out. I've also tried using sha256 instead and it also often times out.

I've done the obvious like increase php memory and increase timeout length but it still happens often.

Would using a different hash algo make it not time out as often?

Comment: `password_hash` is better

Comment: How much data are you hashing that it times out?

Comment: @dean - password_hash has a completely different purpose than a HMAC.